# What is the smallest value of r that gives a test of size not exceeding 0.05?

Tags: r, self-study, binomial-distribution, type-i-and-ii-errors

I've been given a question that I don't understand.

**Question:**
Consider a test which rejects $H_0$ if the number of observed successes is $≥ r$ , where $r$ is some number. What is the smallest value of r that gives a test of size not exceeding 0.05?

We have:

$o=50$ ,for 50 observations

$H_0 : p =1/2$

I know that a test size is the probability of committing a type 1 error, where we falsely reject the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis is true. This happens 5% of the time if our p-value cut off is 0.05.

What I'm not sure about is : "What is the smallest value of r that gives a test of size not exceeding 0.05?"

Because $r$ is just some random number that hasn't been specified, what's stopping me from putting in a large number for $r$ , such as 49?

I've attempted it by using:

$\mu = np$

$\text{SD} = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$

$a =0.05$

```
qnorm(0.95,mean=50*0.5,sd=sqrt(50*0.5*0.5)
```

But this gives me the test value which I don't think is finding what $r$ is.

Comment: "*what's stopping me from putting in a large number for r...?*"  -- the fact that the question *explicitly asks* for the *smallest* one.

Comment: In R: `qbinom(.95, 50, .5)` returns 31. If $X \sim BINOM(50, .5),$ then $P(X \le 31) = .9675;$ $P(X \ge 32) = .0325.$ What about $P(X \ge 31)?$ Too big?